# Launch Selenium WebDriver in current session of Chrome JAVA

Tags: java, google-chrome, session, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using this code to launch Chrome with WebDriver.

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E://ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Please help to open browser in current chrome session. Please use JAVA for solution

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

It means open new Chrome browser. Once you have to open new browser window.

**EDIT** as per your comment

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\chromedriv‌​er.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://google.com"); 
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t"); 
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOp‌​eninNewTab); 
Thread.sleep(2000); 
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles()); 
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1)); 
driver.get("http://facebook.com");
```

Comment: i want to open Session in current session not in new browser window

Comment: @niazi, What mean of `Session`? (You can clear web session by: `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();`)

Comment: Do you want to open a page in a new tab or window ? If yes, then try to avoid it. I was not able to switch between tabs/windows with chromedriver, even when the windows/tabs had different handles. Luckily, my project was such that I could open pages in another browser instance. HTH.

Comment: Hi, @testerjoe2, I have try this code to open new tab.

**Code:**

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://google.com");

String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
Thread.sleep(2000);
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.get("http://facebook.com");`

@niazi, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have try this code to open new tab. @niazi, it will help you.

**Code:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","F:\\chromedriv‌​er.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://google.com");
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOp‌​eninNewTab);
Thread.sleep(2000);
ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(1));
driver.get("http://facebook.com");
```